# Date and Time Picker Widget from Mailbox app

Tags: android, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

Does anyone know what Date and Time Picker widget the [`Mailbox`](http://www.mailboxapp.com) app uses ?

[image: Date and Time Picker from Mailbox]

I'm mostly interested in restricting times by days (think opening hours for particular days) and this seems to be the closest UI the could make that easy by placing listeners on the days and settings restrictions on times based on those. None of the existing pickers available make that convenient. I'm open if anyone knows other implementations that are similar as well.

Comment: Looking for the same thing... Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

YOu can create a custom Dialog like this which helps the user to select both time and date..This [link](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-create-custom-date-time-picker.html) will help you more..There is no default alert box like this you need to customize in the way you want it...

Comment: I was looking more for a library. Almost everything is custom implementable but I assume because they use it someone has made it. So why not use that if it's available.